# Can't we come up with a 404 philosopun?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred

Many SE sites have a funny 404 page. [We don't](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/lalalarandomness).

Can't we come up with some philosopun for the 404 page?

Comment: Usually, funny images are the way to go. Certain stacks have these already; if you've got a suggested image that might work, go ahead and paste it here...

Comment: This won't be implemented until this site graduates, but collecting ideas now doesn't hurt.

Comment: @Shog9 oh, that's too bad :( but thanks for pointing that out and adding the tag!

Answer (score 5):

The [Rabbit–duck illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit%E2%80%93duck_illusion), made famous by Wittgenstein.

[image]

<sup>[*Source*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Duck-Rabbit_illusion.jpg)</sup>

Copyright information in the (linked) source.

---

I just checked my copy of Wittgenstein's [*Philosophical Investigations*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6680512-philosophical-investigations) (pp. 204-204<sup>e</sup>). There this figure appears (or something that's virtually identical; the lines here seem a bit more fat):

[image]

I took this image from http://www.iep.utm.edu/epis-per/. I'm not sure about copyright. It also appears on the covers of the [*Philosophy Bites*](http://www.philosophybites.com) books.

Assuming that this is Wittgenstein's handiwork, I think it is to be preferred over the Jastrow original. But it is a bit late (?) in the game to add it as an new, separate answer. (If you object, let me know in the comments.)

Comment: I'd prefer that one, too.

Answer (score 3):

Copyright should probably be discussed with the source/artist:

[image]

<sup>Source (and copyright?): http://www.philosophers.co.uk</sup>

The picture can be found on at least eleven websites. I'm not sure who, if anyone, holds the copyright. The drawing seems to be by [Frits Ahlefeldt](http://hikingartist.com/about/): *Can a picture say more than a thousand words?* ([Image](http://hikingartist.com/2012/07/26/how-to-draw-a-picture-is-worth-a-thousand-words/).) ("MY DRAWINGS ARE FREE FOR NON COMMERCIAL USE: Artworks here by Frits Ahlefeldt is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs 3.0 Unported License." I have no idea what that means for Philosophy.SE.)

Update: Looking at http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/, I guess it is not an option. At least not without approval by the artist. (Note that the text under the image was removed and that it doesn't carry attribution. Also, I'm unsure whether Philosophy.SE is noncommercial.)

Comment: IANAL but I think the fact it's CC means it's fine for attributed usage (outside certain contexts indicated like derivative works)

Comment: Great image by the way.

Comment: @JosephWeissman TINLA. This is an _altered_ version of the [original](http://hikingartist.com/2012/07/26/how-to-draw-a-picture-is-worth-a-thousand-words/a-picture-is-worth-a-thousand-words-3/). That makes it a derivative work. Also, the alteration removes the attribution, which is bottom-right in the original. If one were to use the picture, I strongly suggest getting an email from the author approving of it. Obviously, the unaltered version wouldn't quite work. And probably there's no space on the 404-page for attribution and/or copyright information.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I'm terrible at puns.

But perhaps we could make a 404 that questions the very existence of the visitor, like:

> That page doesn't exist. By the way, are you sure you exist?

The current form isn't great at all, but perhaps something with the same idea.

Comment: "The page you have requested exists only in your mind." ~Sincerely, A Solipsist

Answer (score 2):

Not funny, not a cartoon, but aesthetically pleasing as well as apropos:

[image]

<sup>[Excerpt](http://www.haverford.edu/news/gallery.php?id=3861) of the letter written by Rene Descartes in 1641. From: [*"Missing" Descartes Letter Discovered in Haverford Archives, Will Be Returned To French Owner*](http://www.haverford.edu/news/stories/35971/51ess).</sup>

Note that the picture doesn't need to be explanatory, because the text on the left of the 404-page explains itself.

I assume that there cannot be any copyright on the image, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'd find this better than the existing answers (probably not), but I'd like to offer at least another point of view: quotes.

> “The role of the artist is to ask questions, not answer them.”
>
> <sup>— Anton Chekhov</sup>